# What component should I use to represent a solenoid valve in multisim

Tags: multisim, solenoid-valve

I'm trying to model a 12V 500 mA pilot assisted solenoid valve in NI Multisim, but it doesn't have any solenoid components that I see. I thought I could just model it with an inductor or relay, but I don't know what component to use or what values to give it. It doesn't need to be exact, just something vaguely approximating the electrical characteristics of a solenoid.

Comment: You can probably model it as an inductor. Take a look at the data sheet for the coil characteristics.

Comment: I'm using a 100uH inductor right now, but the datasheet is ... less than informative. http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-4-12VDC-Electric-Solenoid-Valve-with-Push-In-Connectors-N-C-12-Volt-DC/300838831941?_trksid=p2050601.c100085.m2372&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140211132617%26meid%3D6770175282697905464%26pid%3D100085%26prg%3D20140211132617%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D300838831941%26clkid%3D6770176579144101471&_qi=RTM1562569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't doing anything super-fancy, you can probably safely assume that a 12V 500mA solenoid has an impedance of 12v / 500mA = 24 Ohms.

If it's going to be switched relatively slowly (1/sec is pretty slow), you can assume a 24 Ohm resistor and just remember to put a backwards-facing diode in parallel with the coil to protect your circuitry from the collapsing magnetic field's current when you get ready to build it.

Comment: The diode's already in place :)